# How to create a folder using Zend Framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework, phpmyadmin, zend-form, zend-studio

For example today date is `2012-04-04` so I want `2012` as a parent folder then `201204` as child folder and then `20120404` as sub-child folder. Like

```
2012/201204/20120404
```

How can I create it using Zend Framework?

Comment: If you are ever in doubt of what PHP intrinsically offers, think of the command as it would be in bash or C -- if it exists there, PHP likely has it as the same name. For example: "man mkdir", "man unlink", "man lstat".

Answer (score 5):

Creating folders has nothing to do with Zend Framework! You just use plain PHP for that.

PHP has the [`mkdir()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php) function for that.

I see you listed `Zend_Form` as a tag to your question. So I take it you want to create folders to store files you're uploading via forms. In that case you just have to create the needed folders during the file transfer.

Comment: To be fair it was possible ZF would have a class that handles files.

Comment: yes, but i want to create folders to store files but on 2012->201204->20120404 this sequence. so my file store in 20120404 this folder using zend.

Comment: @Iznogood It does: Zend_Form_Element_File uses Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http; you can specify the upload destination but it must exist first.

Comment: Right. But its always in the context of file uploads. Not a pure file and folders handling.

Comment: @Iznogood as a quick FYI, the ZF team will only wrap intrinsic functionality if there is a significant enhancement to be made or if the intrinsic API is horrific. Since there is only so much one can do regarding creating directories, it is not likely that there would ever be such a component added to ZF. I suppose one could make a case for a filesystem abstraction component, but that solves a completely different set of problems.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like Zend Framework doesn't really have Filesystem related classes.

However, you can still use OOP by using the Directory class.

http://php.net/manual/en/class.directory.php